# How can I open two files using names from a list to store the text from the files in another list

Tags: python

I want to open two text files and store the text in them in a list. This is the code:

```
my_files = ['C:\\rob 1 \\chat.txt', 'C:\\rob 2 \\chat.txt']
storage = [] 
for file_name in my_files:
    text=open(file_name).read()
    storage.append(text)
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: open() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I read the answers for this error type but they had "classes" and my code has no classes. How can I change the code so that the text from the two text files is stored in the list?

Comment: You've redefined the built-in `open()` function somewhere in your code.

Comment: Might be you defined ```open``` unintentionally

Comment: Search your code for `def open` or `from XXX import open`

Comment: checking `open is __builtins__.open` should return True. If it does not, that means it is redefined

Comment: thanks for the help! I did indeed redefine open. Should I delete this question (according to stackoverflow best practice guidelines)?